# Load contents of a file as a list Python

Tags: python

I have a text file that looks like this

```
['M', '>', 'F', 'P', ' ', 'N', 'I', '$', 'F', '\x19', 'J', 'B', 'P', 'T', '%', '<', 'M', 'Q', '>', '\x00', 'I', 'F', 'N', 'J', '\x16', 'X', '\\', 'H']
```

Its already in a list form. 
How do i load it into python as a list without it think that all the separators between the sections are actual characters?

Comment: Usually, the _right_ answer to this question is "don't generate files like that, then you won't need to parse them".

Answer (score 1):

Read the contents as a string, and use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert it into a Python data structure.

That is:

```
import ast
with open('datafile.txt') as f:
    data = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
```

Comment: or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list-in-python

Comment: I still get ['M', '>', 'F', 'P', ' ', 'N', 'I', '$', 'F', '\x19', 'J', 'B', 'P', 'T', '%', '<', 'M', 'Q', '>', '\x00', 'I', 'F', 'N', 'J', '\x16', 'X', '\\', 'H'] as the output.     It was supposed to be "M>FP NI$F..." etc.

Comment: it is a `list`. That is the output you get if you print a list. Please read the [Python tutorial 3.1.3 *Lists*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Comment: To convert it to a string, use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join).